# Crontask Django - создание и администрирование задачи

Tags: python, linux, django, cron

Суть такая: есть кастомная команда в Django, которая вызывается как 
  `python manage.py <команда>` 
Необходимо создать крон задачу, которая каждую минуты вызывала бы данную команду. Как это сделать? 
Дистрибутив Linux Mint.

Comment: Так же, как и любую другую крон-задачу, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если каждую минуту в рабочие дни:

```
* * * * 1-5 python manage.py <команда>
```

Каждые 5 минут:

```
*/5 * * * 1-5 python manage.py <команда>
```

Это если Ваш manage.py не имеет GUI. Если же он пользуется оконным менеджером, то необходимо добавить *export DISPLAY=:0 &&* перед самой командой запуска питона.

Comment: А если использую virtualenv, то сначала необходимо будет активировать virtualenv и затем запускать python manage.py <команда>?

Comment: **virtualenv** - не использовал, так что - врать не буду.